# extent codeigniter Session expiration

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, jquery, session

I have `$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;` on my config.php file, Which means that session last in 2 Hours.

By default the session is created up on user LOGIN. Now i want to last session based on User IDLE state.

So when user is active on page i need to renew the session.

Ex.

A POLL to server on every 2 minutes through ajax with current user status , `IDLE` or `ACTIVE`

if the status is `ACTIVE` then i want to extent/renew/update the session timeout for another 2 hours from the ajax call.

Infact IF the status is `IDLE` i will run a timer on web page and before it reaches its timeout (2 hours)  i need to display a warning to user ==>

"Your Current session is about to expire. Do you want to renew session ?"

If user clicks `YES` then i want to extent the session for another 2 hours,else i will send an LOG OUT command.

So the Question is : How i renew/update/extent the session timeout programically ?

Also is there any other better solutions available.

I am using PHP 5 , Codeigniter 2.x , Bitauth( User Authentication ).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply you can use the `$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 30; //seconds` which will update the  session timeout if user is idle and `session expiration` time is over i.e `$config['sess_expiration']       = 7200;` and then user hits any link it will automatically logged out because CI check the session on each request that whether `session expiration` time is over or not of exceeds the expiration time then your session is destroyed . If user hits any request after one hour then your `sess_time_to_update` updates the `sess_expiration` lets say from now to two hours.
By default, CI creates a new session id in a defined interval `$config['sess_time_to_update']   = 30;` i.e after every 30 seconds new session id will be created

For a deep closely look you can see the `Session.php` in libraries `sess_update()` is the function which updates the session so you have a good idea what CI does if you are not using the `database` session then CI stores the information in cookie else it stores the data in the `ci_sessions` table